# How is made the probable key words of EditView

Tags: android, keyword, editview

(Sorry maybe the Title is sensless)

How can I program, in Android, like what we obtain when we search for a contact in our phone contact list, I mean for example just when we write **jac** in the serch `EditView` we have under it a list like

**Jac** k Andrew (phone number)

**Jac** k Bill (phone number)

**Jac** ob Lym  (phone number)

So in my case I have an array of `String[] myWords` and an `EditView myEditView` I want when writing in `myEditeView` it proposes for me the words from `myWords` which start or contain the written caracters in `myEditeView`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that I would look into the AutoCompleteTextview.

Look at this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: thanks @JoaoFilipeClementeMartin, 
please when it do `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);` what is `R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`

Comment: It is an android predefined element that represents one line in the array.